# Text in a flex container doesn't wrap in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Consider the following snippet:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, the text is wrapping as expected:

[image]

But, in IE11, **the text is not wrapping**:

[image]

Is this a known bug in IE? (if yes, a pointer will be appreciated)

Is there a known workaround?

---

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19138107/247243) doesn't have a definite answer and an official pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 flexbox preventing text wrapping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138107/ie11-flexbox-preventing-text-wrapping)

Comment: The issue goes away when I remove `align-items: center` from the parent element. That seems to be what's causing it

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
.child { width: 100%; }
```

We know that a block-level child is supposed to occupy the full width of the parent.

Chrome understands this.

IE11, for whatever reason, wants an explicit request.

Using `flex-basis: 100%` or `flex: 1` also works.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);       /* NEW; used calc to adjust for parent borders */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Sometimes it will be necessary to sort through the various levels of the HTML structure to pinpoint which container gets the `width: 100%`. [CSS wrap text not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42025810/3597276)

Comment: I had to add width: 100%; to the parent. This bug seems to have various fixes depending on the context. Sigh IE!

Comment: Rather use "max-width: 100%" on the .child.

Comment: I'm creating a table using flex (each row is a flex, with it's children having: `flex: 1 1 50%;  display: flex;  align-items: center;`. Not surprisingly, IE fails while word-wrapping long texts in the cells. Setting `width:100%` works, but setting `min-width: 100%` doesnt! It should, but it doesn't (like all things IE), so I tried `max-width: 99%`, and surprisingly, it *does* work. I think using `width:100%` might be better?

Comment: Or rather, I'd go with `flex-basis:100%`. It'd make more sense, since the cell itself is also a flex container.

Comment: I had to remove `flex-direction: column` on the parent for this to work.

Comment: This issue seems exclusive to flex columns. Doesn't happen with flex rows.

Comment: Flex-basis 100% did it for me, had a strange bug only on IE11 where a line would appear 2 times on print.

Comment: `flex-basis:100%` worked perfectly for my use-case. `.child { width: 100%; }` did not.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same issue and the point is that the element was not adapting its width to the container.

Instead of using `width:100%`, **be consistent** (don't mix the floating model and the flex model) and use flex by adding this:

```
.child { align-self: stretch; }
```

Or:

```
.parent { align-items: stretch; }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, this answer makes sense too (and is probably more correct than the width one). In one of my designs, setting width:100% is not possible, and this solution works well.

Answer (score 12):

As [Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111090/text-in-a-flex-container-doesnt-wrap-in-ie11/45304098#comment73294352_35113633) has suggested in one of the comments here, using

```
max-width: 100%;
```

on the child may work (worked for me). Using `align-self: stretch` only works if you aren't using `align-items: center` (which I did). `width: 100%` only works if you haven't multiple childs inside your flexbox which you want to show side by side.

Comment: max-width worked for me when applied to the same container that align-items:flex-start was placed on.

Answer (score 11):

Hi for me I had to apply the 100% width to its grandparent element. Not its child element(s).

```
.grandparent {
    float:left;
    clear: both;
    width:100%; //fix for IE11 text overflow
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    align-items: center;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I had "width: auto;" on grandparent.  Switching to 100% fixed this for me.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow all these solutions didn't work for me. There is clearly an IE bug in `flex-direction:column`.

I only got it working after removing `flex-direction`:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I've found is just adding max-width: 100% to the element that's going out of bounds. If you're using it on something like a carousel remember to add a class with the max-width attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
.grandparent{
   display: table;
}

.parent{
  display: table-cell
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions did not help me with ".child {width: 100%;}", since I had more complicated markup. However, I found a solution - remove "align-items: center;", and it works for this case too.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to remove `align-items: center`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39365207/630170

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have 100% consistently been able to avoid this flex-direction column  bug is to use a min-width media query to assign a max-width to the child element on desktop sized screens.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

//a media query targeting desktop sort of sized screens
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .child {
        display: block;
        max-width: 500px;//maximimum width of the element on a desktop sized screen
    }
}
```

You will need to set naturally inline child elements (eg. `<span>` or `<a>`) to something other than inline (mainly display:block or display:inline-block) for the fix to work.

Answer (score 0):

Me too I encountered this issue.

The only alternative is to define a width (or max-width) in the child elements. IE 11 is a bit stupid, and me I just spent 20 minutes to realize this solution.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 800px;
  @media (max-width:960px){ // <--- Here we go. The text won't wrap ? we will make it break !
    max-width: 600px;
  }
  @media (max-width:600px){
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  @media (max-width:400px){
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not find my solution here, maybe someone will be useful:

```
.child-with-overflowed-text{
  word-wrap: break-all;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: There is no such value in IE, maybe  `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with overflowing images in a flex wrapper.

Adding either `flex-basis: 100%;` or `flex: 1;` to the overflowing child fixed worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

Why use a complicated solution if a simple one works too?

```
.child {
  white-space: normal;
}
```