# Flexbox flex-direction: column items in flex-direction:row in IE11 is broken

Tags: html, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm trying to do simple grid with flexbox. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/j3w795qo/3/

This example work fine in Chrome, FF, Edge, but no in IE11:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column>* {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* fixing overflow bug in IE*/
}
```

```html
<div class="column" id="column1">
  <p>
    This text will wrap even with ie flex bug. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" id="column2">
    <p>
      This text <strong>WONT WRAP</strong> for some reason even with ie flex bug. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
      anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Text in `#column1` will be wrapped as expected, but anything in `#column2` won't wrap whatever you try.

I know that flexbox in IE is buggy, but I wasn't able to find bug for that. 
It's not a duplicate of [Text in a flex container doesn't wrap in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090) cause text in first column wraps correctly using answer from question above, but when used together with flex row it won't wrap when you set 100% width or `flex-basis` 100%