# How to break words with IE 11 running on WP 8.1?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-11, word-wrap

I'm struggling to get `word-wrap: break-word;` to work on Nokia Lumia 930 (and probably other Windows phones). Any ideas? The text just floats over to the next tab.

It seems to be working ok in iOS and Android.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: white;
}

.tabs {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.tab:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <span class="label">xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <span class="label">xxxxxx xx xxxxx</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <span class="label">xxxx xxxxxx</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <span class="label">xxxxxx xx</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The model number is irrelevant, what matters is the version of the OS, and by extension, the browser and its version.

Comment: OS: Windows Phone 8.1 (8.10.14.234.375), Browser: IE 11

Comment: related: [Why IE11 doesn't wrap the text in flexbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111090/why-ie11-doesnt-wrap-the-text-in-flexbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `align-self: stretch` to `.label` solves it.

```
.label{
   align-self: stretch
}
```