# How can I wrap the text in IE?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In Chrome and Firefox it displays correctly, but in Internet Explorer the text overlaps. How can I display the text correctly so that it works for IE?

[image]

In Chrome and Firefox it displays like below. I want it display the same for IE.

[image]

Code CSS & HTML

```css
.chart[id*="Chart_Column"] .ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.ct-chart-bar .ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
    -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-anchor: start;
}
<style>…</style>
.chart[id*="Chart_Column"] .ct-label {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
    -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-pack: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
    text-anchor: start;
}
.ct-chart-bar .ct-label, .ct-chart-line .ct-label {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.ct-label {
    color: #111111;
    fill: #111111;
}
```

```html
<g class="ct-labels">
<text class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 79px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Avg Players Per Match</text>
<text class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 79px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Depth of Selection</text>
<text class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 79px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">% of overs bowled</text>
<text class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 79px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">% of balls faced</text>
<text class="ct-label ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 79px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">% of matches played</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Assign a width to the label.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111090/why-ie11-doesnt-wrap-the-text-in-flexbox