# Word wrap not working on flex item in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following code I have a flex row container with a nested flex column container. In the flex column container it seems as though word wrap does not work.

```css
.profile-header {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile-header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.picture {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.name {
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-header-container">
    <div class="picture">
      
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name">
        reallylongfirstname reallylonglastname
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.name` element doesn't seem to want to word wrap in internet explorer, where it seems to work fine in chrome. I checked flex bugs, specifically, bug #2, but setting `max-width: 100%` didn't seem to work. Is there a way I can make this work?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkg2wwe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS table to achieve the same layout.

```css
.profile-header {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.profile-header-container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
.picture,
.info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.picture {
  display: block;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.info {
  text-align: center;
}
.name {
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header">
  <div class="profile-header-container">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name">
        reallyrealylongfirstname reallyreallylonglastname
      </div>
      <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yjffbff/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like it works. However, in doing some reading I came across different opinions about not using tables for layout. Obviously if this solves my problem I will use it, but do you care to comment about the negative opinion of tables used for layouts?

Comment: @user4584963 Those opinions are saying not to use html <table> for layout not css table I believe. Consider flexbox is an advanced version of css table in many ways, and it's still being developed and kind of buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Flex layout in Internet Explorer is known to have several bugs.

A text wrapping problem is detailed here: *[Why IE11 doesn't wrap the text in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090/3597276)*

The text wrapping problem in IE is often solved by defining a width at the right place or places.

In this particular case, defining widths for the text element and the parent seems to fix the problem.

Add this to your code:

```
.info { width: 50%; }

.name { width: 100%; }
```

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkg2wwe/3/)

Comment: Can you think of a way that I can make it so the `.name` element only takes up what it needs to so I don't have to set the width to always be 50%? Sometimes the names will be short and I need the `.info` div to always be centered.

Comment: Looks like I can accomplish this by adding `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to `.profile-header`. Then I can set `.info { width: 100% }`.

Comment: Was playing with it for a while. No easy fix for IE11 that I can see. Maybe consider ellipsis instead of wrap? Tested and works in IE11. http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkg2wwe/5/