# CSS wrap text not working in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing some problems with some styles that are working properly in both Chrome and Firefox, but they don't in IE.

The problem I'm facing basically is that a particular style applied works fine in Chrome but it does not in IE. Text does not wrap into the column.

How to reproduce it? Take a look at [**this fiddle**](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/wgjrVP) first in Chrome or Firefox, and then do it in IE.

[image]

To make things easier, try it directly from here:

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.jc-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
.column-item-x2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.jc-start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.resume-item {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: medium;
  right: 15px;
}
.dot {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  right: 37px;
}
.dot-skill {
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.skill {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="resume" class="Container column" style=" margin-top: 50px;">
  <span style="textAlign: left; fontSize: 40px; color: red;">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Resume-chk" style="display: none;" />
          <b id="Resume-title">RESUME</b>
        </span>
  <hr />
  <div class="Container row jc-center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="Container column jc-start column-item-x2" id="professional" style="color: red;">
      <div class="Container row" style="border-left: solid 2px #B4B2B2; padding-left: 30px;">
        <div style="text-align: left;">
          <h2 style="color: red;">PROFESSIONAL</h2>

          <div class="Container column">
            <div class="Container row">
              <div class="dot" style="background-color: red;"></div>
              <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                <span class="resume-item" style="color: white; background-color: red;"><b>Nov 2016 - Present</b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              <h3>Web.com</h3>
              <p style="color: gray;">
                <span>
       Actualmente trabajo como Engineer III Fullstack .NET en Web.com,
       una compañía con fuerte posición en el mercado norteamericano de eCommerce. <br />
       Realizo mantenimiento y nuevos desarrollos tanto back-end como front-end
       del portal de ticketing de la compañía.
      </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Container column jc-start column-item-x2" id="personal" style="color: red;">
      <div class="Container row" style="border-left: solid 2px #B4B2B2; padding-left: 30px">
        <div style="text-align: left;">
          <h2 style="color: red;">SKILLS</h2>
          <div class="Container column">

            <div>
              <div class="Container row">
                <div class="dot" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div style="position: relative;">
                  <span class="resume-item" style="padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 6px; text-align: left; color: red;"><b>C#</b></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Container row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: red;" />
                <div class="dot-skill" style="background-color: #B4B2B2;" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Container row" style="border-left: solid 2px #B4B2B2; padding-left: 30px;">
        <div style="text-align: left;" }}>
          <h3 style="color: red;">OTHER_SKILLS</h3>
          <div class="Container row" style="margin-left: 15px; flex-wrap: wrap;" }}>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">TDD</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">Scrum</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">MongoDB</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">ElasticSearch</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">Flux</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">Firebase</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">.Net MVC 5</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">REST Services</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">SOA</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">OAuth</span>
            <span class="resume-item skill" style="font-size: small; color: white; background-color: red;">ExpressJS</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has a problem with wrapping in flexbox.

The normal fix is to define a width for the container.

What is not always clear is: which container?

In this case, these adjustments seem to work:

```
#professional > .row > div { width: 100%; }

#personal .row .row .row > div { width: 100%; }
```

[**revised fiddle**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oByNeL)

Related: [Why IE11 doesn't wrap the text in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090/3597276)

Comment: It should be noted that if you are using `flex-direction: column`, then this solution would have you setting the element `height` instead of `width`.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work. But what is the criteria you used to get this suggestion?