# Flex elements not wrapping text in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to create multi tab groups with headers using CSS flexbox layout.
I'm running into an issue where some elements are not wrapping text in IE11.

I have tried other similar issues discussed on Stack Overflow, by adding `weight:100%` to children, or using `flex: 1` or `flex: 1 auto`, and none of those have resolved the issue.

https://codepen.io/Oboluse/pen/mmNaoR

```css
.tabSection {
  display: flex;
}
h3 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.tabGroup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.header {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
.tabGroupParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid green
}
.tab {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabSection">
    <div class="tabGroupParent">
        <span class="header">header</span>
        <div class="tabGroup">
            <h3 class="tab">
                column value stuff stuff 1
            </h3>
            <h3 class="tab">
                column value stuff stuff 2
            </h3>
            <h3 class="tab">
                column value stuff stuff 3
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabGroupParent">
        <span class="header">header</span>
        <div class="tabGroup">
            <h3 class="tab">
                column value stuff stuff 4
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have noticed if I remove `flex-direction: column;` from `.tabGroupParent`, then the child elements start wrapping in IE11 but I lose my header. Is there another way to achieve centered header in this case? or how can I get the children elements to wrap in IE11 without removing `flex-direction: column`?

[image: text not wrapping in IE, this looks good in Chrome/Firefox]

Comment: `.tabGroupParent { width: 100% }` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmXgLX

Comment: the child text elements now wrap but the problem is that the tab groups now expand to 100% of screen. I can have variable number of tabs under each group, so if each tab group has one tab they will still occupy 100% of monitor with lots of empty space in between. The original page in Chrome is what I'm trying to reproduce in IE11

Comment: IE11 has many flexbox-related bugs ([**flexbugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)). I tried a bunch of workarounds,  including `display: inline-flex` for the containers, but nothing worked. Doesn't mean there isn't a solution. Just means that all fixes I'm aware of aren't working in this case. Good luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111090/why-ie11-doesnt-wrap-the-text-in-flexbox

Comment: Aside from the fact that `weight: 100%` is obviously supposed to be `height` or `width`, this doesn't appear to be reproducible in IE11 for me. It is exactly the same there as it is in Firefox and Chrome latest as of mid-Jan 2019.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add browser prefix like below

```
.tabGroupParent {
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   // flex-direction: column;
   border: 3px solid green
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't fix the issue