# Incorrect image sizing in IE11 in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to position an image in a div. It should be centered. The div should have a minimum width and it should grow only if text below the image requires it.

The following code demonstrates what I want in Chrome:

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.loading-spinner-overlay-1 {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 300px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loading-spinner-overlay-2 {
    left: 0;
    top: 300px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 600px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loading-spinner-background {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.loading-spinner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.loading-spinner-container > img {
    margin: auto;
}

.loading-spinner-container > p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
<div class="loading-spinner-overlay-1">
  <div class="loading-spinner-background">
    <div class="loading-spinner-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="loading-spinner-overlay-2">
  <div class="loading-spinner-background">
    <div class="loading-spinner-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      <p>
      Some long text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, in IE11, it looks like this:

[image: ie11]

**Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in IE11?**

What can I do to fix this?

I have tried setting `max-width: 100%` and `flex-shrink:0` on the `img` tag as some google results suggest, but this didn't help.

Comment: Are you adding the proper vendor prefixes, or using a tool like Autoprefixer to do it automatically? https://autoprefixer.github.io

Comment: @TedWhitehead: No, I haven't, but as far as I can tell, no such prefixes are necessary. I have created a fiddle with the CSS from Autoprefixer and it suffers from the same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/DHilgarth/hterd97n/

Comment: I think it’s an issue with placehold.it, IE can’t determine the intrinsic size of the image. It seems to work fine with http://satyr.io/40x40 instead, or if you add an inline `width` attribute to the img tag.

Comment: @TedWhitehead: Well, I have built this example based on my real app. In my app, I am using a gif, not an image from placehold.it... Also, there is no difference when using your placeholder. It's the exact same problem.

Comment: @TedWhitehead: Explicitly setting the width and height of the img tag to the size of the image in pixels will fix the problem, right. But that is not a real solution as the image might be replaced by another with a different size.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, my fiddle hadn’t updated (lag time in Browserstack). I think you will need to add the inline `width` attribute. You could also check out https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs for known issues.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you need to use flexbox on `.loading-spinner-container`? If not, you could do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/bf3zqoj9/

Comment: @TedWhitehead The issue with that approach is that the image is not centered if there is no text... :/

Comment: You mean vertically? What if we move the margin to the `<p>` instead of the `<img>`? https://jsfiddle.net/r1f3wptt/

Comment: Yes, vertically. In your latest example, the white background no longer is square...

Comment: It looks like this in Chrome: https://www.screencast.com/t/7GIf9tG9WHm5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated*

Adding `align-items: flex-start` to the `loading-spinner-container` fixes the issue, which kind of make sense, since `align-items` default is `stretch` and works cross axis (in this case horizontal) for flex column direction.

*Updated, 2nd revision*

Additionally, to fix the vertical centering, and since IE11 again has some issues when it comes to `min-height`, remove `flex-direction: column` from the `loading-spinner-background` and move `min-height: 100px` to `loading-spinner-container`.

Stack snippet

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.loading-spinner-overlay-1 {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 300px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loading-spinner-overlay-2 {
    left: 0;
    top: 300px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: calc(100% - 600px);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loading-spinner-background {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column;                  removed  */
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.loading-spinner-container {
    min-height: 60px;                       /*  added/value changed (moved from *-background class)  */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: flex-start;                /*  added  */
}

.loading-spinner-container > img {
    margin: auto;
}

.loading-spinner-container > p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
<div class="loading-spinner-overlay-1">
  <div class="loading-spinner-background">
    <div class="loading-spinner-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="loading-spinner-overlay-2">
  <div class="loading-spinner-background">
    <div class="loading-spinner-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      <p>
      Some long text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also `align-items: center` can be used, and if combined with `justify-content: center`, you can drop the `margin: auto` on the `img`.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4mj99ur2/)

---

*Updated, 3rd revision, based on a comment*

Longer text appears to not wrap on IE.

As shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111090/why-ie11-doesnt-wrap-the-text-in-flexbox), IE need to have the width set explicit on the flex item, here `p`, and since also `loading-spinner-container` is a flex *column* item (for *row* item `flex-grow` is enough), it needs one too (or `overflow: hidden`).

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4mj99ur2/4/)

Comment: Thanks, thats great :-)

Comment: There still is a problem. If the text is very long, it doesn't wrap around in IE11: https://jsfiddle.net/4mj99ur2/1/. Setting `width:100%` on the container and on the `p` solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="loading-spinner-overlay-2">
  <div class="loading-spinner-background">
    <div class="loading-spinner-container">
      <div class="img-container">  <!-- added this -->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
        <p>
            Some long textwrwerwer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then added new class:

```
.loading-spinner-container .img-container {
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Basically I added a wrapping div.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the image size. I know that this is a solution.

Comment: That still doesn't produce the desired result