# max-width not working in IE11 with display: table container and display: flex children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In the code below, all is displayed correctly in Chrome. The width of the `.inner` element is restricted by `max-width`.

In IE11, the `.inner` element stretched to all content.

If I set `display: block` for `.container` or `.inner` element all works correctly. But I can't do this because this example is a short reproduction of error in large component that used on many sites and I don't want to break something.

1. Why it happens?
2. How to fix it?

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 277px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">77 777 777 77 7 7777 77 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 77 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 7</div>
  <div class="inner">111 11111 111111111111 111111111111 111111111 111111111111 11111111111 11111111111 11111111 1111111111 11111</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can expect [problems with flexbox in IE11](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

Throw in a `<table>` element as the parent of flex containers (normally the children of a table are table cells), and you're now looking for trouble.

Finally, add [overflowing content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090/3597276), and you're just begging IE11 to break your layout.

That said, the solution to the problem is to add two rules to your code:

```css
 .container {
   width: 100%;              /* new */
   table-layout: fixed;      /* new */
   display: table;
   max-width: 277px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: yellow;
 }

 .inner {
   background-color: red;
   display: flex;
   height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">77 777 777 77 7 7777 77 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 77 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 77 7 7 7 7 7</div>
  <div class="inner">111 11111 111111111111 111111111111 111111111 111111111111 11111111111 11111111111 11111111 1111111111 11111</div>
</div>
```