# flexbox text wrap on Internet Explorer 11 (IE11)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In the code below the paragraphs are not getting wrapped on small screen while using Internet Explorer 11. By searching for solutions I found that if `flex-basis:100%` or `width:100%` is applied on `.fix` div then the paragraphs get wrapped but this method breaks my layout. What can be the possible solution that will

1. Keep my layout intact
2. The paragraphs will get wrapped on small screen

Output of the Internet Explorer 11:

[image: Internet Explorer flexbox bug example]

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}

.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
  <div class='fix'>
    <div class='container-2'>
      <p>Center Aligned Content</p>
      <p>Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running up against a couple of problems involving flex and/or IE11.

Try this:

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fix {
  display: flex;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
  <div class='fix'>
    <div class='container-2'>
      <p>Center Aligned Content</p>
      <p>Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an explanation of the problems:

- [Text in a flex container doesn't wrap in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090/3597276)
- [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/3597276)

Comment: Setting .fix to 100% width will breaks layout on large screen. On .container-1 justify-content:flex-end will not has any effect.

Comment: @MirajulMomin, answer revised.

Comment: I got it. Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can automatically set the `fix` width. We need to use JavaScript to set it. If the window is resized to a size that `container-1` width is the same as `container-2` width, then we can set the `fix` width to 100%. If we resize back, then we remove the `fix` width.

For the working demo, you could refer to the sample below which has been tested in IE 11:

```js
var c1 = document.getElementsByClassName('container-1')[0];
var c2 = document.getElementsByClassName('container-2')[0];
var fix = document.getElementsByClassName('fix')[0];
document.getElementById('c2').innerText = c2.offsetWidth;
var c2width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c2').innerText);

function setStyle() {
  if (c1.offsetWidth <= c2.offsetWidth) {
    fix.style.width = '100%';
  }
  if (c2.offsetWidth > c2width) {
    fix.style.width = '';
  }
}

window.onresize = setStyle;
```

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
  <div class='fix'>
    <div class='container-2'>
      <p>Center Aligned Content</p>
      <p>Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c2" style="display:none"></div>
```

The result in IE 11 is like below:

[image]

Comment: That is a solution but an HTML document can has many occurrences of this type of layout. For every occurrence applying this method maybe inefficient.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I can come up with till now and it's applicable to the situation in your thread. I'll continue to research if there's any other solution.

Comment: I don't think JS is necessary. See my answer for a clean CSS solution.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

After long research I found that if `.fix` div has `overflow:hidden` style then the problem is solved.

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fix {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
  <div class='fix'>
    <div class='container-2'>
      <p>Center Aligned Content</p>
      <p>Some content goes here. Some content goes here. Some content goes here. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```